# How to use REGEXP_REPLACE to convert a verbal BOOLEAN collection of words to MATCH AGAINST format? [MySQL 8.0.36]

Tags: mysql, regex, regexp-replace

I need to convert a text query from standard "verbal" boolean to the FULLLTEXT MATCH AGAINST + and - system.

For example; this value:

```
((word1 AND word2) OR (word3 AND word4 AND word5)) OR word6 NOT word7
```

Needs to be converted to:

```
((+word1 +word2) (+word3 +word4 +word5) word6 -word7
```

The issue I'm having is when I try to use REGEXP_REPLACE with a pattern like this:

```
\\b([[:alnum:]_]+)\\b
```

I can't figure out how to have the function use the word that matched to append/amend to it. I've seen other examples trying to use \1 or something like that to represent the matching value, but it simply doesn't work.

So how can I command REGEXP_REPLACE to dynamically scan a string for "(word +word" and replace it with "(+word +word" ? Also needs to do a leading simple one like:

It's also a bit more complex, because if we have:

```
(word1 AND word2) AND (word3 OR word4)
```

That would need to be:

```
+(+word1 +word2) +(word3 word4)
```

Any guidance on the best way to do this without writing an ultra slow parser would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `$1`, `$2`, etc. in the replacement string to get the corresponding capture group.

Comment: @Barmar that's EXACTLY what I was looking for! This is NUTS! I searched high and low and everyone was using \\1 \\2 etc. Even OpenAI couldn't figure out to use $1 and $2. And I don't think I saw it documented anywhere... Where is this documented?

Comment: I can't find it in the MySQL documentation.

Comment: @Barmar what pattern do you recommend I use to meet what's presented above? If you want to post it as an answer, I'll give you the credit. Thanks a ton for this. Crazy it's not documented anywhere and other posts use \\1 under 8.0 Q&A.

Comment: The question is already closed as a duplicate, no answers can be posted.

Comment: I don't think your more complex problem can be solved with a regular expression. They can't be used to detect balanced parentheses.

Comment: @Barmar I can write code that does that; I just need to basically say if a trailing word has + in front of it, put a + in front of the word before it if it doesn't have a +.

Comment: @Barmar I posted the solution above; thanks again for your help - amazing the MySQL documentation has absolutely no examples of $1 and everyone else uses the MariaDB //1 reference. Seems this is a bit of a secret that's pretty important for people to know.

Comment: Found this bug report: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=113153

Comment: @Barmar thanks! Crazy how the admins are still marking this as a duplicate question when it is most certainly not.

Comment: I did that, not the admins. Then you completely changed the question, that's not appropriate.

Comment: The core of the question did not change. I only enhanced the title and added the answer. This is useful information for developers that might be seeking such a solution. Marking it as something it's not because one doesn't like the way the resolution was achieved is not a reasonable reason to mark it as a dupe.

Comment: I've reopened the question, you can post your answer now.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar. Since you provided the key ingredient for solving the problem ($1) please post your answer and I will award it to you while also keeping the details I provided. I hope this helps other developers in the future.

Comment: My answer was just a duplicate of the question I linked to, it didn't solve the larger problem.

Comment: @Floobinator, the answer doesn't belong in the original post. Please revert that, and instead post the answer in the section below.

Comment: @trincot thank you for the reminder; been a VERY busy week. Edited and posted!

Comment: I suggest doing the transliteration in your application code.  SQL is not very powerful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to convert a AND/OR/NOT boolean statement like the below to a compatible MATCH AGAINST solution, and hope this helps other people.

This converts:

```
(word1 OR word2) OR (word3 AND word4 AND word5) OR word6 NOT word7
```

TO

```
(WORD1 WORD2) (+WORD3 +WORD4 +WORD5) WORD6 -WORD7
```

CODE:

```
SET in_text_search = '(word1 OR word2) OR (word3 AND word4 AND word5) OR word6 NOT word7';
SET text_reformatted = UCASE(TRIM(in_text_search));
SET text_reformatted = REPLACE(text_reformatted,'  ',' '); -- Strip extra spaces

-- Make sure the count of parentheses (if exist) is equal.
IF (INSTR(text_reformatted,'(') > 0 OR INSTR(text_reformatted,')') > 0) THEN
        SET count_character = LENGTH(text_reformatted) - LENGTH(REPLACE(text_reformatted,'(',''));
        IF (count_character <> (LENGTH(text_reformatted) - LENGTH(REPLACE(text_reformatted,')','')))) THEN
                -- TRIGGER ERROR 'imbalanced parentheses';
                LEAVE SP;
        END IF;
END IF;

SET text_reformatted = REPLACE(text_reformatted,' AND ',' +');
SET text_reformatted = REPLACE(text_reformatted,' OR ',' ');
SET text_reformatted = REPLACE(text_reformatted,' NOT ',' -');

-- Primary replace
SET text_reformatted = REGEXP_REPLACE(text_reformatted, '(?<![-+])\\b(\\w+)\\b(?=(?:\\s*\\+|\\s*$))', '+$1', 1, 0, 'c');

-- Cleanup the cart before the horse, for words like .NET etc.
SET text_reformatted = REPLACE(text_reformatted,'.+','+.');
SET text_reformatted = REPLACE(text_reformatted,'.-','-.');
```

Answer (score 0):

In a way, this SQL-style solution was made for fun, but maybe it will help someone.

```
with RECURSIVE
  t1(in_text_search) as (
    values
      row('(word1 OR word2) and .net AND (word3 AND word4 AND word5) OR word6 NOT word7')
  ),
  r as (
    select
      0 as occ,
      cast('' as char(127)) as tok,
      in_text_search,
      0 as parentheses,
      cast('process' as char(30)) as status
    from t1
    union all
    select
      r.occ+1,
      case
        when t.tok = 'AND' then '+'
        when t.tok = 'NOT' then '-'
        when t.tok = 'OR' then ' '
        else coalesce(t.tok, '')
      end,
      r.in_text_search,
      p.parentheses,
      case
        when p.parentheses < 0 then 'imbalanced parentheses'
        when t.tok is null then
          case
            when p.parentheses != 0 then 'imbalanced parentheses'
            else 'done'
          end
        else 'process'
      end
    from r,
    LATERAL(
      select
        ucase(regexp_substr(
          r.in_text_search,
          '[()]|[^()[:space:]]+',
          1,
          r.occ+1
        )) as tok
    ) as t,
    LATERAL(
      select
        r.parentheses +
          case
            when t.tok like '(' then 1
            when t.tok like ')' then -1
            else 0
          end as parentheses
    ) as p
    where status = 'process'
  ),
  t2 as (
    select
      occ,
      tok,
      lead(tok, 2) over(order by occ) as tok_2nd,
      status
    from r
  ),
  t3 as (
    select
      occ,
      case
        when tok = '(' and tok_2nd in ('+', '-') then concat(tok, tok_2nd)
        when tok in ('+', '-') then concat(' ', tok)
        else tok
      end as tok,
      status
    from t2
  )
select
  GROUP_CONCAT(tok order by occ separator '') as text_reformatted
from t3
;
```

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|                     text_reformatted                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| (WORD1 WORD2) +.NET +(+WORD3 +WORD4 +WORD5) WORD6 -WORD7 |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SWaZQWKR)